# Docker Swarm Inspect to get internal IP from every node

Tags: parsing, docker, docker-swarm

I'm trying to get the internal (container level) IP from a service that is deployed globally on several swarm nodes.

Something similar to this.

```
docker node ls -q | xargs docker node inspect -f '{{ .ID }} [{{ .Description.Hostname }}]: {{ .Spec.Labels }} {{ .Status.Addr  }}'
```

This returns the host IP for every node and the labels on those hosts.

I began retrieving all the IDs for a specific service across all nodes using:

```
docker service ps [swarm_task] -q
```

And then inspect each one of it like this:

```
docker service ps [swarm_task] -q | xargs docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworksAttachments.Addresses }}'
```

But the IP Address is in a different format and I get this error:

`Template parsing error: template: :1:23: executing "" at <.NetworksAttachments...>: can't evaluate field Addresses in type interface {}`

The format inside the inspect is this:

```
"Addresses": [
                "10.0.0.187/24"
            ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument to docker `--format` is a standard go [text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) expression.

As `NetworksAttachments` is an array, you may have to iterate on `NetworksAttachments` to get a valid output.

The [`range`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/#parent-command) keyword is designed to do that:

```
$ docker service ps [swarm service name] -q --filter "desired-state=Running" \
| xargs docker inspect --format '{{range .NetworksAttachments}}{{.Addresses}}{{end}}'
```

My docker engine output is :

```
[10.x.x.y/16]
[10.x.x.z/16]
```

I added the `--filter "desired-state=Running"` to `docker service ps` to focus on running containers only.

You can refer to Go [text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) documentation:

> {{range pipeline}} T1 {{end}}
>
> The value of the pipeline must be an array, slice, map, or channel.
>       If the value of the pipeline has length zero, nothing is output;
>       otherwise, dot is set to the successive elements of the array,
>       slice, or map and T1 is executed. If the value is a map and the
>       keys are of basic type with a defined order ("comparable"), the
>       elements will be visited in sorted key order.